# Ruby-On-Rails qrcode.as_svg doesn't generate images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qr-code

I have been stuck for the past two days with this. When I try to generate an image of my qr code i get something weird. Doesnt matter what format. For example when I use the "normal" format it works.
`<%= qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new("http://github.com/") %> gives me the expect result.`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewboE.png)

However when I do:
`<%= svg = qrcode.as_svg( offset: 0, color: "000", shape_rendering: 'crispEdges', module_size: 6, standalone: true ) %>`
I get something really weird. I tried importing images through the normal way adding svg files to my assets images file and it works fine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3Fev.png)

Any idea what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting SVG to HTML as text. Use the html_safe method to apply HTML tags from a variable you are inserting.

```rb
<%= qrcode.as_svg( offset: 0, color: "000", shape_rendering: 'crispEdges', module_size: 6, standalone: true ).html_safe %>
```

Comment: Working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome) pls upvote my solution, and mark mine as the right decision))

Comment: hey sorry for the late reply but since my account is new you cant see i upvoted your solution and marked as correct

Answer (score 0):

You can also use as well in case you want to call any helper:

```
:ruby
  @qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new(url: 'www.google.es').as_svg


= raw @qrcode.html_safe
```

For me looks much cleaner.